# Crystal Reports HP Simplified font issue when generate PDF

Tags: crystal-reports

I use HP Simplified font in my report. But when I'm trying to export it I get the message.

```
The selected program does not support the export of one of the functions, which uses
smiling in this report.
The report used partially compatible HP Simplified fonts; Use TrueType font  instead of them.
```

What I need to do, to use this font?